# iOS App testing - Low Budget Solution

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, device

So I am currently building my first iOS iPhone App which I plan to launch in the coming months. I have now finished my app but I don't have a big budget so testing on multiple devices is difficult. I already have an iPad so I assume that could run an iPhone version just to check that all the code is working. If I know that the code can run on an actual iOS device (the iPad) will the simulator suffice for the rest of testing would you think? I do plan to use test flight later on in the project too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could launch your app on your iPad with iphone mode. Just select option 'iPohne' as on screenshot below

[image]

Using simulator gives you some restrictions. For examle, you can not test full process of in-app purchase, location, ads, etc. So, if you are using some of this features for your specific platoform, it's better to test it on the actual device

Comment: Ok. I am using iAds so if I were to test on iPhone mode on the iPad then i should be ok to see the how the banners work etc. Other than that, the simulator would work for sizing and everything?

Comment: also testing notifications are not available using simulator. as for sizing/ common navigation - ok, but i recommned you enable 'release' mode by editing your scheme. that will make your build closer to real situation. you may use, for example, HockeyApp in order to test your release build configuration.

Comment: Ok great, I never knew about the release mode when using simulator. I think I will have to make do using a bit of both which as atm there are no notifications, should work ok...

Comment: just out of interest what are the benefits of release mode that make it 'closer to a real situation'? Thanks

Comment: the release and debug builds are not identical, they have different optimisation level, so could be differences on generated binaries. Hope, i' ve answered your question :).

Comment: Ok thanks that's great. I think I'll have to make do with the stuff I have at the moment :)

Comment: @dwinnbrown, you are welcome) please, vote and mark post if it was useful for you :)